Unable to deserialise ProblemDetails Extensions property
I am facing an issue when deserializing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails object,
basically Extension property is not return  back to the client
I have writted a simple test webapi app in .NET8 C# as follows
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<ActionResult<WeatherForecast> > GetProblemDetails()
 {
     var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
     {
         Status = 404,
         Title = "test x",
         Extensions = new Dictionary<string, object?>
     {
                           { "errors", new[] { "Company xxxxx not found." } },
         { "traceId", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
                       }
     };


     return new ObjectResult( problemDetails);
 }

I have configure the controller to use NewtonsoftJson to serialise in Program.cs

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

When I call the method from postman the Extension property is not returned,
result from postman
I also wrote a console app to call the api using restsharp and get the same result
from console app
what I am doing wrong?
